# How to use CSRF token in Silex 2 via Twig template?

Tags: symfony, twig, csrf, silex

i've registred a **CsrfServiceProvider()**

```
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\CsrfServiceProvider());
```

My form:

```
<form action="{{ url('some.action') }}" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="blah-blah" value="" placeholder="">
  <input type="hidden" name="_csrf_token" value="">{# how to output SCRF token here? #}
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
```

Thank you for any assistance!

**Solution** (my interpretation of [V-Light](https://stackoverflow.com/users/348193/v-light) answer)

**Controller:**

```
$app->get('/', function() use ($app) {
  $tokenId = 'intention';
  $csrf_token = $app['csrf.token_manager']->getToken($tokenId);

  return $app['twig']->render('home.twig', [
    'csrf_token' => $csrf_token,
  ]);
})->bind('home');
```

**Template:**
`<input type="hidden" name="_csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token }}">`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you don't use `Forms` from symfony (FormServiceProvide ins silex world) and do not have form twig-helpers like

```
<input type="hidden" name="_csrf_token" value="{{- csrf_token('intention') -}}">
```

But **try first anyway**, maybe my assumption isn't correct und it works already :)

#### FormServiceProvider

try to install [Forms for Silex](https://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.0/providers/form.html)

then look at the [Usage documentaion-block of CSRF for Silex](https://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.0/providers/csrf.html#usage)

> When the CSRF Service Provider is registered, all forms created via the Form Service Provider are protected against CSRF by default.

so it's pretty self-explaining ;) The only thing you should do - create your forms with FormServiceProvider (see documentation) and render them properly in twig instead just writing plain-old html by yourself.

but...

> You can also use the CSRF protection even without using the Symfony Form component.:

At this point you could either create your own twig-helpers and so on or
just use

```
$tokenId = 'intention'; 
$csrf_token = $app['csrf.token_manager']->getToken($tokenId);
```

and then pass `$csrf_token` variable to your twig-view and use it in the form like

Of cource, checking if given/submitted token is valid - your job each time you've submited a form with csrf-token (see Usage part of CSRF documentation for Silex)

Comment: Thank you for answer! it's woked for me )) i'll describe the way in nexr comment

Comment: Could you please provide the way on how to check if the csrf_token from the login form is valid?